# LinqToSql and Stored Procedure question

Tags: linq-to-sql, stored-procedures, poco

I have a stored procedure that returns a number of fields, pew row. Is there anyway i can define the class which the stored procedure 'goes into', instead of it using the auto-generated class?

The class i want the results to populate is a POCO, not another LinqToSql table.

Is this possible? i'm assuming that the poco class public properties are the same names as the fields in the returned recordset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can define your own complex type and then select it in function import

[image: Define complex type]
[image: Function import]

Comment: Wow. a question i asked 5 years ago! Boy it's been 5 years also since I've done L2S .... where has the time, gone! So here, have some points for being so kind and the necro badge :)

Comment: Lol ) i just found unanswered question and desided to help )